# KNN with categorical values can not predict correctly

Tags: random-forest, dataset, scikit-learn, k-nearest-neighbour

I am trying to build a model that given an item, predicts which store it belongs to.

I have a data-set of ~250 records which are supposed to be items in different online stores.

Each record is composed of:  Category,Sub Category,Price,Store Identifier(The y variable)

I have tried several number of neighbors, tried Manhattan distance but unfortunately can not get better results accuracy ~0.55. Random Forest produces accuracy ~0.7.

My intuition says that a model should be able to predict this problem. What am I missing?

This is the data: https://pastebin.com/nUsSbkp4

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

labelencoder_X_0 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 0] = labelencoder_X_0.fit_transform(X[:, 0])

labelencoder_X_1 = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 1] = labelencoder_X_1.fit_transform(X[:, 1])

onehotencoder_0 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [0])
X = onehotencoder_0.fit_transform(X).toarray()

onehotencoder_1 = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features = [1])
X = onehotencoder_1.fit_transform(X).toarray()

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0)
# classifier = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=25, criterion='entropy', random_state = 0)
classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, metric='minkowski', p=2)
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

accuracy = classifier.score(X_test, y_test) 
print(accuracy)
```